# Is the determinant a function from $M_n(\mathbb F_p) \to \mathbb R$ or is it a function from $M_n(\mathbb F_p) \to \mathbb F_p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

I am trying to answer the following question from Artin section 3.2 on Fields.

> Determine the primes $p$ such that the matrix
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
>       1 & 2 & 0\\
>       0 & 3 & -1\\
>       -2 & 0 & 2
>    \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   is invertible, when its entries are considered to be in $\mathbb F_p$.

We know the determinant of this matrix is $10$. But **is the determinant a function from $M_n(\mathbb F_p) \to \mathbb R$ or is it a function from $M_n(\mathbb F_p) \to \mathbb F_p$?**

If $\det$ is a map to $\mathbb R$, then $\det A=0$ only when $p=2$, but if $\det$ is a map to $\mathbb F_p$, then $\det A=0$ when $p=2$ and $p=5$.

Comment: If $R$ is a commutative ring, then the determinant is a map from $M_n(R)$ to $R$.

Comment: I'm not totally competent here, but I assume its codomain is $\Bbb F_p$ just like the determinant of a complex matrix is a complex number.

Comment: I just figured out that we can have the codomain as $\mathbb C$, and the answer will still be $p=2$ and $p=5$. This is because, we can choose different representatives for the entries of the matrix modulo $p$ so that we still get determinant $0$ without reducing the determinant modulo $p$ in the codomain.

Comment: It takes values in $\mathbb{F}_p$. The $\det A$ is a polynomial in the entries of $A$, which lie in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Note that the nonzero vector $(1,2,1)\in\Bbb{F}_5^3$ is mapped to $0$, so the matrix is not invertible when its entries are considered to be in $\Bbb{F}_5$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that for any $A$ in $M_n(R)$, $R$ a commutative ring, we have the formula
$$ A \operatorname{adj}{(A)} = (\det{A})I,$$
where adj is the adjugate matrix, which is defined from the elements of $A$ using ring operations, and so lives in $M_n(R)$. Thus the left-hand side is the product of two matrices in $M_n(R)$, so the right-hand side must also be. Then if $A \in M_n(F)$ a field $F$, $A$ is invertible, with inverse $(\det{A})^{-1}\operatorname{adj}{(A)}$, if and only if $\det{A}$ is invertible in $F$, which is if and only if $\det{A} \neq 0$ in $F$.

Hence the sensible thing to do (so that the determinant performs a useful function, namely determining invertibility) is say that $\det: M_n(F) \to F$, and form the determinant using the operations of $F$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the two simplest interesting cases:
$$
\det (a)=a\quad\text{and}\quad\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=ad-bc
$$
Note that these formulas are universal in the sense that whatever ring $R$ your quantities $a,b,c,d$ come from, the value is in that ring $R$. Especially in the case of the $1$-by-$1$ matrix, there’s no conceivable way that an element of {integers modulo $n$} can be given a meaning in the reals, since $1$ and $n+1$ are the same, as things modulo $n$.

For $n$-by-$n$ matrices, it’s the same story. You have the formula for the determinant, big and messy as it may be, and it always delivers a value to you that’s in the ring that you started in. Never a real number, unless your ring can be considered a subring of $\Bbb R$.